# How to echo a special character into a file?

Tags: bash, sed, echo, special-characters

I have a shell script which does all kinds of things.

Among them, it checks if a certain line exists in /etc/rc.local, if the line doesn't exist, I'd like to add it to the file.

```
grep reboot "/etc/rc.local" || echo -e "sed -i 's/\^reboot//g' $script" >> /etc/rc.local
```

The problem is that i'm unable to insert the special character "^" to the file.

So if I just run the line, without the redirection to /etc/rc.local:

```
# grep reboot  "/etc/rc.local" || echo -e 'sed -i "s/\^reboot//g" $script' >> /etc/rc.local
sed -i 's/reboot//g' /root/1.sh
```

You can see that the echo'ed line misses the "^" .

I've tried with and without the "-e" switch of echo, tried with double/single quotes... nothing works - I can't seem to echo the special char.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need `^reboot` in any script compared to just `reboot` ?

Comment: This script upgrades the kernel, then reboots and continues running. this line in /etc/rc.local is supposed to remove the "reboot" command from the script before running again to complete the rest of the tasks - this is done to avoid getting in a reboot loop. I want the command to remove only the line in the script which contains the reboot command and thus the "^" as the reboot command in by itself in the line. There are other places in the script where there's a reboot but I don't want to touch the other lines, only the one that actually reboots.

Comment: My question still stands, why literal `^reboot` ? or are you looking for lines, where you have only `reboot` in the line and nothing else ?

Comment: Exactly - there's only one line which contains only reboot and that's the line I want to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat inputfile
some reboot
reboot
some reboot other
```

Remove line that has only `reboot` and nothing else.

```
$ sed '/^reboot$/d' inputfile
some reboot
some reboot other
```

Use `-i` to remove it in-place and overwrite `inputfile`.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a line that has "reboot" at the beginning, use

```
grep -v '^reboot' /etc/rc.local > result
```